# What does the dot (period) mean before an object name?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am converting a Foxpro 7 app and there is a statement I see in about 200 places in the code which says:

```
LOCAL LcAlias as string

LcAlias = .LcAlias && This is the line in question

SELECT(LcAlias)
```

I don't know what .LcAlias represents, what the dot (period) indicates or how it's populated. I've done full searches of the all the readable objects in the project directory but I just can't determine how .LcAlias is being filled with data. The only thing I could find on the net is a reference to a previous WITH block but the code above appears at the very top of the code page and it is not contained within a WITH block.

If anyone has a clue for this perpetual Foxpro n00b I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly somewhere before this code, there's a line like this:

```
WITH SomethingOrOther
```

and somewhere below it is:

```
ENDWITH
```

That means that .lcAlias here is SomethingOrOther.lcAlias.

Comment: The posted code is at the top of the code page before anything else. There isn't a WITH anywhere in the entire code page. I can give no guarantees that the Foxpro code is correct. I will look into what you've said. Thank you though for reading and responding.

Comment: Ok so I was wrong. My code page was only a partial and that code is indeed within a WITH block. This causes me to ask another question. The code above is within a block like this: WITH Thisform (the code above) ENDWITH. So my issue, bearing in mind that the .lcalias is really thisform.lcalias, is that there is no object on this form with the name lcalias. I looked at all the objects with no luck. If it's some sort of "form level variable" I can't find where it's being set. Anyway I don't expect anything on this but if you (or anyone) can offer some insight I would be most grateful. Thanks!

Comment: @GunnerFan420, the .lcAlias is probably a PROPERTY on the form.  Look at the PROPERTIES sheet.  "lc" is notation of a localized-character data type value.  Also known as Hungarian notation.  Since VFP is loose on its data typing, it helps someone looking at code have SOME idea of what data type to be expecting in the field.  ex: "ln" local-numeric, "ll" local-logical, etc.

Comment: @DRapp is right. When you see the notation Thisform.Something, it tells you that "Something" is a property or method of the form. (For a method, you'd expect parens afterward.) The question then is where it's getting set. It might be in the Property Sheet or in the form code.

Comment: Thank you both for the info. I finally found it after looking for a whole day. It was indeed a property on the form. The reason I didn't find it is that, in the Properties window, there is a big alphabetical list in which lcalias didn't appear. Well I edited the raw .SCT file and I could see it was a property.The issue? There is a SECOND alphabetical list of properties after the first list. Since it started with an L I had never scrolled all the way down. So sorry for being a bucket head and many thanks for helping me solve my issue.

Comment: Just as a note I figured out why there were two alphabetical lists. Foxpro does something I've not seen in my 25 years in technology. They use case sensitivity when sorting alphabetically. So the properties in the first list start with a capital letter (A) while the second list starts with a lower case letter (a). Unbelievable but at least the mystery has been solved.

Comment: Yes, we pushed the VFP team to change that sorting of the Property sheet, but never succeeded. There is one benefit of the current sort, which is that built-in PEMs always start with upper-case, and most VFP developers use lower-case to start custom PEMS, so they tend to sort separately. But I'd rather they'd have fixed it.